# Which codes does the front oxygen sensor throw?

Tags: o2-sensor, electronic-control-module, evap

I have these three O2 related sensor error codes. Are they all codes for the front 02 sensor (the one in-front of the catalytic converter) ?

```
P1133 - HO2S Insufficient Switching Bank 1 Sensor 1
P0133 - O2 Sensor Circuit Slow Response Bank 1 Sensor 1
P0130 - O2 Sensor Circuit Bank 1 Sensor 1
```

My car is a Saturn Ion 2003

Comment: Yes, the "sensor 1 " in the description line denotes this as a pre-catalyst sensor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://o2sensors.com.au/static/o2-sensor-identification-and-locations :

> So what is Sensor 1? Sensor 1 is the O2 sensor that is located before
>   or upstream of the catalytic converter. (Pre-cat)
>
> So then if your diagnostic code is B1 S2 that means Bank 1 Sensor 2
>   down stream (post-cat). If its B2 S2 that means Bank 2 (opposite Bank
>   to Bank 1) and the downstream after cat o2 sensor.

Since all of your codes are bank 1, sensor 1, they are all coming from the same pre-cat O2 sensor.